# Problems with a prime making machine

Tags: python

I don't know why this is saying that all numbers are prime (i know that this code is pretty noobish):

```
number = 3
a = 1
import time
while a == 1:
    for counter in range(2,number):
        result = number%counter
        counter = counter + 1
    if result == 0:
        print(str(number) + " is not a prime")
    else:
        print(str(number) + " is a prime")
    number = number + 1
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

Comment: Do you know what a prime number is? A number is prime iff it's divisible only by one and itself. Your code doesn't check for this condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code for you:

```
import time
number = 3
a = 1
while a == 1:
   for counter in range(2,number):
      result = number%counter
      if result == 0:
         print(str(number) + " is not a prime")
         break;
   if result != 0:
      print(str(number) + " is a prime")
   number = number + 1
   time.sleep(0.25)
```

Now I'll tell you each problem you had and why it was a problem.

**1. Putting your prime check outside the loop**

```
    if result == 0:
       print(str(number) + " is not a prime")
```

Result will only be checked at the conclusion of the loop. Ensuring that only the last possible "factor" will be checked. Note that if you check numbers up to half of the value and there is no factor then the number is prime (I didn't include that).

**2. Incrementing Counter**

```
counter = counter + 1
```

For loops are incremented each time by default.

---

So yours was always going to be prime because the remainder of dividing a number starting with three from one less than that number will never be zero.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful